# How to see a merge history?

Tags: git, merge

I'm using git but I'm not an expert with it.

I inherited a legacy project and it follows git flow (and I like it): each new feature in a `feature/name` branch. But when new features were merged into `develop` main branch they were not erased from `origin`. So that now in origin I see a lot of branches and I don't know which one are old one or which are working-progress.

Is there a way to have an history of the merges done between feature branches and the develop?

EDIT: I'm on a linux machine

Comment: you are using windows or Iinux

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To get a history of merge commits made in the current branch, use the following command:

```
git log --merges
```

Comment: wouldn't this skip/ingore fast-forwarded merges?

Comment: Correct: fast-forward merges are not real merges - they are just a stack of commits

Answer (score 0):

can I offer another suggestion, that you search for the branches with head revisions that are included in the history of your develop branch ?  It protects you from losing changes that were committed to a branch that had previously merged.

Something along these lines :

```
git log --oneline develop > /path/develop.log

# Just in case anyone's broken process and committed a bugfix directly to a release branch
git branch -a | grep 'remotes\/origin\/release\/' | while read branch; 
do 
    git log --oneline $branch > /path/"$branch".log; 
done

git branch -r | while read branch;
do
    git log -1 --oneline $branch | awk '{print $1}' | while read commitID;
    do 
        if grep -rq $commitID "/path/" ;
        then 
            echo "git push --delete origin \"$branch\"    Deletable   $commitID";
            break;
        #else 
            # the head revision hasn't been committed to any 'master' branch
            # echo "$branch $commitID"; 
        fi; 
    done; 
done
```

Answer (score -2):

install this

```
sudo apt-get install git-gui
```

and run gui command to execute

```
git gui
```

Comment: I cannot agree with this answer on a number of issues.  Firstly, it is not necessarily distro agnostic.  As well, it assumes the user is necessarily using a Window Manager, which was not stated.  And a final issue for me is that it is not so much of an answer, insomuch as it is a quick suggestion that *might* be useful to the OP, but not necessarily to other distro users that might come across the answer.

The accepted answer, on the other hand, is one that not only works for the OP, but anyone else who has git installed and comes to this question.

Comment: @PaulBeverage That's pretty hypercritical. I think this is answer is an option for the vast majority of people who will see it. Even if they can't `apt-get` it, git-gui is likely available. I mean, this isn't just some random, half-assed tool. It's referenced on git-scm.com. Probably not the "best" answer, but still relevant and helpful.

Comment: @Jeff -- Making one or more assumptions does not lean towards the makings of a good answer, which is what Dharani did here.  Similarly, pointing out that an answer has used assumptions at its core does not make my comment "hypercritical."  This is a site based on facts and applicability -- I personally do not find this answer to be appropriate to the question's given context from the OP.  The accepted answer, on the other hand, is perfectly applicable in every situation, including that of the OP.

Comment: @PaulBeverage I say it's "hyper"-critical because there is a downvote on the answer, which doesn't seem warranted in this case (if the downvote isn't yours then that's a bad assumption on my part). OP states that he's new to git, which possibly implies that they'd benefit from a gui representation rather than the command line output of the accepted answer. And OP is on linux. It seems unlikely that they'd be asking this question _and_ using a distro w/o a window manager.

Comment: @PaulBeverage Would this answer be appropriate if OP had stated "I'm on Ubuntu, and have a Window Manager capable of supporting git-gui..." If you were "just pointing at that an answer has an assumption", you might say something like "this assumes a debian-based distro with a window manager"--not "I cannot agree" and "answer... [not] appropriate".